# while iterating create multiple objects if property inside List has multiple objects

Tags: java, collections, java-8

I have list which i am iterating and getting the values and setting in another object.

```
List<PersonInfo> personInfo = new ArrayList<>();

myResponseList.forEach(resp->{
  PersonStackBuilder person = new PersonStackBuilder();
  person.setPersonID(resp.getProjectID());
  person.setPersonAreaCode(resp.getPersonAreaCode());
  ...
  resp.getPersonAccountable().forEach(acc ->{
    
    person.setPersonMortgageId(acc.getMortId());
    ....
    ..
   });
 personInfo.add(person);
});
```

`resp.getPersonAccountable()` is a List and sometimes there could be more than one element(object).When there are more
than one element in `resp.getPersonAccountable()` ,i need to create another person object(PersonStackBuilder) for which it will have the
same personID,personAreacode but with other personAccountable information. How can i create another person object(PersonStackBuilder) if
`resp.getPersonAccountable()` size is more than 1 and has more objects.

Answer (score 0):

---

you should add the person info inside the 'Accountable forEach',
and deep copy the person object in each iteration.
something like this:

```
List<PersonInfo> personInfo = new ArrayList<>();

    myResponseList.forEach(resp->{
      PersonStackBuilder person = new PersonStackBuilder();
      person.setPersonID(resp.getProjectID());
      person.setPersonAreaCode(resp.getPersonAreaCode());
      
      resp.getPersonAccountable().forEach(acc ->{
          PersonStackBuilder personWithAccount = person.clone();
          personWithAccount.setPersonMortgageId(acc.getMortId());
          personInfo.add(personWithAccount);
       });
    });
```

Comment: Can we do without clone, as PersonStackBuilder is not implementing cloneable and i cannot use clone()

Comment: you can deep copy it manually... but the principle is the same.

Answer (score 0):

It is better to use `Stream.flatMap` for the list of accounts returned by `resp.getPersonAccountable()` and assuming that there is an all-arg constructor for `PersonStackBuilder` the code could be written without `forEach` at all:

```java
List<PersonStackBuilder> personInfo = myResponseList
    .stream()
    .flatMap(resp -> resp.getPersonAccountable().stream().map(acc -> 
        new PersonStackBuilder(
            resp.getProjectID(), resp.getPersonAreaCode(), // ... other resp fields
            acc.getMortId()                                // ... other acc fields
        )
    )) // Stream<PersonStackBuilder>
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Or, possibly `PersonStackBuilder` should be refactored and re-implemented as a real `Builder` of `PersonInfo` objects to get rid of a constructor with a long list of arguments:

```java
List<PersonInfo> personInfo = myResponseList
    .stream()
    .flatMap(resp -> resp.getPersonAccountable().stream().map(acc -> 
        PersonInfoBuilder.builder()
            .withProjectId(resp.getProjectID())
            .withAreaCode(resp.getPersonAreaCode())
            // and other fields from resp
            .withMortgageId(acc.getMortId())
            // and other fields from acc
        .build()
    )) // Stream<PersonInfo>
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Or a special factory method can be implemented to instantiate a `PersonStackBuilder` from a given couple of `resp` and `acc`:

```java
List<PersonStackBuilder> personInfo = myResponseList
    .stream()
    .flatMap(resp -> resp.getPersonAccountable()
            .stream()
            .map(acc -> buildPersonStack(resp, acc))
    )  // Stream<PersonStackBuilder>
    .collect(Collectors.toList());

// ...
static PersonStackBuilder buildPersonStack(MyResponse resp, MyAccount acc) {
    PersonStackBuilder person = new PersonStackBuilder();
    person.setPersonID(resp.getProjectID());
    person.setPersonAreaCode(resp.getPersonAreaCode());

    person.setPersonMortgageId(acc.getMortId());

    return person;
}
```